# Dynamic form fields using #states array on empty select field

Tags: javascript

Trying to make the second field only visible when there is a value in the first controller field. If nothing is selected in the initial load of the screen, the second field should be hidden.

Because the controller api_title is a sub array I'm not sure how to set the comparison value in condition name='api_title'

```
$form['api_title_filter_widget'] = array('#tree' => true, '#weight' => '10');
$form['api_title_filter_widget']['api_title'] = array(
        '#type' => 'select',
        '#title' => 'API Title',
        '#default_value' => $api,
        '#options' => ["" => "- Select -"] + $published_api_proxies,
        '#ajax' => array(
            'event' => 'change',
            'callback' => 'callback_api_product_filter',
            'method' => 'replace',
            'wrapper' => 'api_products_controlled_by_filter',
        ),
    );

$form['api_product']['#states'] = array(                                              
                                   'visible' => array(   
                                        '**select[name="api_title"]' =>** 
                                          array('!value' => ''),  
                                            ),
                                         );
```

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can try to add an id to your select field

```
$form['api_title_filter_widget']['api_title'] = [
  '#type' => 'select',
  '#title' => 'API Title',
  '#default_value' => $api,
  '#options' => ["" => "- Select -"] + $published_api_proxies,
  '#ajax' => [
    'event' => 'change',
    'callback' => 'callback_api_product_filter',
    'method' => 'replace',
    'wrapper' => 'api_products_controlled_by_filter',
  ],
  '#attributes' => [
    'id' => 'my_api_title'
  ],
];
```

Then you should be able to target it through its id :

```
$form['api_product']['#states'] = [
  'visible' => [
    ':select[id="my_api_title"]' => ['filled' => TRUE],
  ],
];
```

Comment: Good news is that adding '#attributes' => [    'id' => 'my_api_title' hid the field but now the ajax call in the controller doesn't work.

Comment: There are two issues with #states and AJAX https://www.drupal.org/node/1091852 and https://www.drupal.org/node/2226405